# Delimiting text string based off of muliple critera instead of charector in MS Access Query

Tags: ms-access

I have a field with varying strings of concatenated text that I need to delimit. I need the phrase and the count of how many times that phrase appeared into two separate fields and then repeating the same process for every additional phrase.

Example of table field text:

"some text":2; some:other NEAR text:1;

Desired Results:

[Field 1]: "Some Text", [Field 2]: 2, [Field 3]: some:other NEAR text, [Field 4] 1

The problem I am having is that when I use ":" and ";" to delimit the field using Len, Instr, InstrRev, Left, Right and Mid functions it is delimiting the "some:other NEAR text" string into "some" and "other NEAR text". Is there a way around this or should I go about this in another way? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a one-time fix of bad data to parse into discrete fields? Should show your attempted code.

Assuming every record has value in the example structure, try (x represents your concatenated data field):

Field1: `Left(x, InStr(x, ":")-1)`

Field2: `Val(Mid(Left(x, InStr(x, ";")),InStrRev(Left(x, InStr(x, ";")),":")+1))`

Field3: `Mid(x, InStr(x, ";")+2, Len(Mid(x, InStr(x, ";")+2))-Len(Mid(x,InStrRev(x,":"))))`

Field4: `Val(Mid(x,InStrRev(x,":")+1))`

Otherwise, might have to build a custom VBA function.